# Angular routing to named rout from another parent

Tags: angular, routes, web-deployment, angular-router

How do you do fellow kids.

I'm new to angular and trying to build a proper rout navigation system
I have this routs so far:

```
{path: 'welcome',
  component: WelcomeComponent,
  children: [
    {path: 'login',
      component: LoginComponent,
    outlet: 'welcomeR'},
    {path: 'register',
      component: RegistrationComponent,
      outlet: 'welcomeR'},
    {path: '',
      component: StartComponent
    }
  ]},
  { path: 'user',
    component: UserComponent,
    canActivate: [RoutProtectionService],
    children: [
      {path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      redirectTo: 'profile'},
      {path: 'profile',
       component: ProfileComponent,
        outlet: 'userR'
      },
      { path: 'browseTutors',
        component: TutorsBrowseComponent,
        outlet: 'userR'
      }]
  },
  {path: '**',
  redirectTo: '/welcome'}
```

As you can see from the structure I have a `<router outlet>` in my app component, and userR/welcomeR routs as subFolders in it.

On successful login I want to redirect to user/profile component but I can't figure out how to do it...
If I'm using something like this:

```
      this.router.navigate([{outlets: { userR: ['profile']}}] );
```

It cant match any rout.
If I'm navigating to `['/user']` I don't get a profile displayed.
I've also tried other methods listed on similar questions but they seem to not work. For example:

```
  this.router.navigate(['/user','profile'];
```

I've tried to delete 
outlet:'userR' and then accessing it with '/user/profile', but with this approach, the content of the profile is not displayed.

As an alternative I've also tried to set a redirect to 'profile' on '' path in user component which didn't work either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure you have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the following components: `AppComponent`, `WelcomeCompoonent` and `UserComponent` template.  Then do not use named outlet in your route definition or in your navigation.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Hope you'll have a nice day and will stay healthy.

Comment: Thanks you too =)

Answer (score 0):

I always use a baseRouterComponent that contains `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
it the parent route object.

To redirect you can use `router.navigateByUrl("/user")`

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dg6sab?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents.ts)

Comment: I'm sorry but I've probably didn't properly understand your answer. Anyways, thank you for your time and response. I hope you'll have a nice day and stay healthy.